# Export to excel is not working while binding DataTable in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is My Code Snippet to Rendering the DataTable objects into Excel.But When i Click on ExporttoExcel Button i'm not able to get data into the excel instead i'm getting all the page controls in my excel sheet.Any help would be really needful.Thanks in Advance.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnExport" runat="server" Text="ExporttoExcel" OnClick="ExporttoExcel"/>

protected void ExporttoExcel(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    DataTable dt=GetValues();
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Data.xls");
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.Charset = "utf-8";
    string tab = "";
    foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
    {
        Response.Write("<b>");
        Response.Write(tab + column.ColumnName.ToString());
        Response.Write("</b>");
        tab = "\t";
    }
    Response.Write("\n");
    int i;
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        tab = "";
        for (i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            Response.Write(tab + row[i].ToString());
            tab = "\t";
        }
        Response.Write("\n");
    }

    Response.Flush();
}

public DataTable GetValues()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

    // Here we add five DataRows.
    table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
    table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
    table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
    table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
    table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);
    return table;    
}
```

Comment: show your code for this method GetValues()

Comment: put the actual code within that method in your post.

Answer (score 1):

The method I used to create excel file is by using `gridview` control.
With the help of `gridview` control you can create excel file easily.
In below code I am filling `gridview` with data of `datatable` and use `RenderControl` method to generate HTML and then save it to a file with a .xls extension

```
protected void ExporttoExcel(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    DataTable dt = GetValues();        
    var grid = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView();
    grid.ShowHeaderWhenEmpty = true;        
    grid.DataSource = dt;


    grid.DataBind();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Data.xls");
    Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    grid.RenderControl(htw);
    Response.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.End();               
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used below code and it worked for me. You have to share your GetValue function definition with us so we can help you.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnExport" runat="server" Text="ExporttoExcel"/>

protected void    ExporttoExcel(object sender EventArgs args)
{
    dtCity = city.GetAllCity();//your datatable
    string attachment = "attachment; filename=city.xls";
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    string tab = "";
    foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
    {
        Response.Write(tab + dc.ColumnName);
        tab = "\t";
    }
    Response.Write("\n");
    int i;
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        tab = "";
        for (i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            Response.Write(tab + dr[i].ToString());
            tab = "\t";
        }
        Response.Write("\n");
    }
    Response.End();
}
```